# How to get the image base address in the code when compiling with GCC?

Tags: gcc, linker, embedded

I'm doing embedded programming with GCC. How could I get the image base address in the C code?

P.S. I know I could set-up a variable in the linker script. But is there any other way to achieve it without bother to modify the script?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you don't want to explicitly set the base address but you want to know what the base address was set to as part of the output.

You can generate a map file as part of the compile by passing an argument to the linker. For example:

```
gcc -Wall -o hello_world.exe -Wl,-Map,hello_world.map hello_world.c
```

The relevant section being `-Wl,-Map,hello_world.map` meaning you are passing the `-Map` option to the linker and telling it to generate the file `hello_world.map`.

The resultant output has a lot of information in it but you would be looking for a section like the following:

```
Linker script and memory map

            0x00400000                __image_base__ = 0x400000
            0x00000000                __dll__ = 0x0
            0x00400000                ___ImageBase = 0x400000
            0x00001000                __section_alignment__ = 0x1000
            0x00000200                __file_alignment__ = 0x200
            0x00000004                __major_os_version__ = 0x4
            0x00000000                __minor_os_version__ = 0x0
            0x00000001                __major_image_version__ = 0x1
            0x00000000                __minor_image_version__ = 0x0
            0x00000004                __major_subsystem_version__ = 0x4
            0x00000000                __minor_subsystem_version__ = 0x0
            0x00000003                __subsystem__ = 0x3
            0x00200000                __size_of_stack_reserve__ = 0x200000
            0x00001000                __size_of_stack_commit__ = 0x1000
            0x00100000                __size_of_heap_reserve__ = 0x100000
            0x00001000                __size_of_heap_commit__ = 0x1000
            0x00000000                __loader_flags__ = 0x0
            0x00008000                __dll_characteristics__ = 0x8000
```

The image's base address should be clearly visible as well as the locations of your stack, heap (if you have one), and all of your functions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I want to use the base address in the program code such as like `read_the_code_from(Image_Base)`. Since I'm doing embedded programming and there is no standard linker script. I wonder there is a "standard variable" to point to it.

Comment: @Grissiom I do not know of anyway to do that. But the location shouldn't really change.

Comment: Nop, it may change in some condition. For example, a bootloader may load the fw into different address depend on the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a scatter file, you can easily refer to different regions.
Imagine you want to refer to TEXT section of your scatter file that is base of your code:

`extern uint32_t Image$$TEXT$$Base;`